# Activity stream missing after JIRA upgrade

Tags: upgrade, jira, activity-streams

I upgraded our JIRA from version 6 to version 6.1. Suddenly the Activity Streams are always empty. It is very annoying for the users who were very dependent on them. So I need to get the activity streams back.

What I have tried so far:
1. Reindexing
2. Creating a new widget for activity stream

What log can I look into to see what is broken? Do I need to create a new filter or something?

Comment: Can you see *atlassian-jira.log*?

Comment: The log shows this "Error occurred while retrieving gadget spec for rest/gadgets/1.0/g/com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activitystream-gadget/gadgets/activitystream-gadget.xml" The file does not exist locally. Should I create it?

Answer (score 1):

Please do not create *activitystream-gadget.xml*. Instead, remove the gadgets you have now and install the latest versions of each--including the [Activity Stream gadget](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+the+Activity+Stream+Gadget) itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your `atlassian-jira.log` file.
Mostly this is caused by outdated plugins using deprecated (and now removed) classes. Similar thing happened to me when OSUser class was removed due to deprecation and an older plugin still used it.
If you are not able to view the log, try disabling user installed plugins.